# Angular UI Bootstrap installation help...I cannot figure this out

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I consider myself above novice with some web development experience, and have been practicing Angular. However, I'm not finding the answer on how to implement this one step from the angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap page.

It says to download the package to add it to my project, and to add this to the Angular module:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

I cannot find the life of me through searching stackoverflow, or tutorials on where to add this in my project.

Now, I did use a CLI command in the project directory:

```
npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-beta
```

Testing this with the bootstrap tags in my divs shows that it works, just not the programming part to have the interactive content work.

Would someone mind pointing me in the right direction or clarify what I'm missing here?

Thank you all for your help!

---edit---

```
AHONCIAN-M-X2UY:bootstrap ahoncian$ npm ls --depth=0
bootstrap@0.0.0 /Users/ahoncian/OneDrive/angulartraining/bootstrap/bootstrap
├── @angular/common@2.4.10
├── @angular/compiler@2.4.10
├── @angular/compiler-cli@2.4.10
├── @angular/core@2.4.10
├── @angular/forms@2.4.10
├── @angular/http@2.4.10
├── @angular/platform-browser@2.4.10
├── @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.4.10
├── @angular/router@3.4.10
├── @types/jasmine@2.5.38
├── @types/node@6.0.88
├── angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.28.3
├── angular-ui-bootstrap@2.5.0 extraneous
├── codelyzer@2.0.1
├── core-js@2.5.1
├── jasmine-core@2.5.2
├── jasmine-spec-reporter@2.5.0
├── karma@1.2.0
├── karma-chrome-launcher@2.2.0
├── karma-cli@1.0.1
├── karma-jasmine@1.1.0
├── karma-remap-istanbul@0.2.2
├── protractor@4.0.14
├── rxjs@5.4.3
├── ts-helpers@1.1.2
├── ts-node@1.2.1
├── tslint@4.5.1
├── typescript@2.0.10
└── zone.js@0.7.8

npm ERR! extraneous: angular-ui-bootstrap@2.5.0 /Users/ahoncian/OneDrive/angulartraining/bootstrap/bootstrap/node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap
npm ERR! extraneous: tsickle@0.2.5 /Users/ahoncian/OneDrive/angulartraining/bootstrap/bootstrap/node_modules/@angular-cli/ast-tools/node_modules/tsickle
AHONCIAN-M-X2UY:bootstrap ahoncian$
```

Comment: Your question is tagged with `angular` (as in angular 2/4) but the syntax you're using is `AngularJS` (as in angular 1). Which are you using? The whole angular framework is not compatible across major versions 1 and 2. In your project root, try `npm ls --depth=0` and please edit your question with the output of that command.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I've edited with the info.

Comment: msanford is spot on. angular-ui-bootstrap is for AngularJS (i.e. version 1.x). You're using Angular 2+, which is a completely different framework. Note, BTW, that you're using an obsolete version (current version is 4.3.x), and an obsolete version of angular cli, too (current version is 1.3.2). If you want the equivalent of angular-ui-bootstrap for Angular 4.x, use [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home). Make sure to read the documentation to know the requirements.

Comment: JBNizet and msanford Thank you so much! This is most likely why I'm pulling my hair out.